# PyCharm not responding to new environment variables

Tags: bash, pycharm, environment-variables

I am using PyCharm 2018.2.4 and python 3.6.5 with MacOS 10.14.1. I changed an environment variable in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export TFHUB_CACHE_DIR=~/tf_cache
```

I tried this with my terminal, and it looks normal:

```
vpn-global-dhcp1-86:~ myname$ echo $TFHUB_CACHE_DIR 
/Users/myname/tf_cache
```

In Python console, it also works fine:

```
vpn-global-dhcp1-86:~ myname$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jul  1 2018, 14:38:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv("TFHUB_CACHE_DIR")
'/Users/myname/tf_cache'
>>>
```

But when I run the same script in PyCharm, I have the following output:

```
/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/cache
```

which is the old value of `TFHUB_CACHE_DIR`.

Comment: You probably need to restart PyCharm in order to make it recognize an environment variable change.

Comment: @quant Thanks! It works. Maybe you can post this as an answer. I think someone could have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to restart PyCharm in order to make it recognize an environment variable change.